# what is the absolute path for kubernetes pods logs?

Tags: logging, kubernetes, containers, logstash

What is the absolute path for kubernetes pods logs?
When I tried `kubectl logs pod`, I can see logs of pod. I want to know the log file path of running pod.

kubectl logs npapp-0r9jw

```
output: rectory /hab/pkgs/core/tomcat8/8.5.9/20170514144202/tc/webapps/ROOT has finished in 21 ms
national-parks.default(O): 22-Oct-2017 05:33:54.526 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /hab/pkgs/core/tomcat8/8.5.9/20170514144202/tc/webapps/manager
national-parks.default(O): 22-Oct-2017 05:33:54.564 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /hab/pkgs/core/tomcat8/8.5.9/20170514144202/tc/webapps/manager has finished in 38 ms
national-parks.default(O): 22-Oct-2017 05:33:54.564 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /hab/pkgs/core/tomcat8/8.5.9/20170514144202/tc/webapps/host-manager
national-parks.default(O): 22-Oct-2017 05:33:54.595 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /hab/pkgs/core/tomcat8/8.5.9/20170514144202/tc/webapps/host-manager has finished in 31 ms
national-parks.default(O): 22-Oct-2017 05:33:54.599 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]
national-parks.default(O): 22-Oct-2017 05:33:54.613 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
national-parks.default(O): 22-Oct-2017 05:33:54.620 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 2735 ms
```

Where can I see absolute log file path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into [Kubernetes sources](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes), you will see [`pkg/routes/logs.go`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/routes/logs.go), which will serve the content of files within (by default) `/var/log` (serving static files [following this example](https://github.com/emicklei/go-restful/blob/master/examples/restful-serve-static.go))

```
func logFileHandler(req *restful.Request, resp *restful.Response) {
    logdir := "/var/log"
    actual := path.Join(logdir, req.PathParameter("logpath"))
    http.ServeFile(resp.ResponseWriter, req.Request, actual)
}
```

As you can see in [kubernetes/kubernetes issue 53022](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/53022):

> The current symlink `/var/log/containers` is pointing to `/var/log/pods/pod_UID/*.logs`

So the full absolute path for logs is:

```
/var/log/pods/pod_UID/*.logs
```

---

Update 2019:

This issue also refers to [analytics-platform-helm-charts PR 91](https://github.com/ministryofjustice/analytics-platform-helm-charts/pull/91):

> Symlink /var/log/containers has been deprecated in favor of `/var/log/pods` for our version of the docker daemon for kubernetes metadata.

See this [Kubernetes CRI](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/node/kubelet-cri-logging.md#proposed-solution) (Nov. 2018)

> Kubelet will be configured with a root directory (e.g., `/var/log/pods` or `/var/lib/kubelet/logs/`) to store all container logs. 
>   Below is an example of a path to the log of a container in a pod.
>
> ```
> /var/log/pods/<podUID>/<containerName>_<instance#>.log
> ```
>
> In CRI, this is implemented by setting the pod-level log directory when creating the pod sandbox, and passing the relative container log path when creating a container.
>
> ```
> PodSandboxConfig.LogDirectory: /var/log/pods/<podUID>/
> ContainerConfig.LogPath: <containerName>_<instance#>.log
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by VonC is not 100% accurate - it should be `/var/log/pods/<namespace>_<pod_name>_<pod_id>/<container_name>/*.log`

---

Also, the location of the actual log files depends on the container runtime you're using. Docker stores its container logs at `/var/lib/docker/containers`.

When working with Kubernetes, you can access container logs using the absolute log path `/var/log/pods/<namespace>_<pod_name>_<pod_id>/<container_name>/*.log`. These `.log` files symlinks to the actual log files stored by the container runtime.